# Rolling a die 100 times and adding results

Tags: probability-distributions, estimation, central-limit-theorem

Simple problem. We role a die 100 times and we add the results. What is the probability of getting sum between 330 and 380 ?

I got this: 
$P(330  \le  X  \le  380) = P\left(  \frac{330 - n * EX}{\sigma =   \sqrt{100 * \frac{1}{6} * \frac{5}{6}}  }  \le Y  \le  \frac{380 - n * EX}{\sigma =   \sqrt{100 * \frac{1}{6} * \frac{5}{6}}  }  \right) = P\left(  \frac{-20}{3,72} \le Y \le  \frac{30}{3,72}  \right)$

But obviusly something is wrong. What and why ? $\sigma^2$? or what?

Comment: how do you find $\mu=EX$? and $E[(X-\mu)^2]$? this is a good starting point, and dont forget to mention that $X_i$ are independent from each other.

Comment: $EX = 1 * \frac{1}{6} + 2 * \frac{1}{6} +...+ 6 * \frac{1}{6} = 3,5$
And $Var[X] = E(X^2) - (EX)^2 = (1* \frac{1}{6} + 2^2 * \frac{1}{6} +...+ 6^2 * \frac{1}{6}) - 3,5^2 = 0,5$ Is it correct?

Comment: yes it is.(5 more to go...)

Comment: Could you se my solution in a comment down this site ?

Comment: Andre had already written an answer therefore i Ieft it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_i$ be the number obtained  on the $i$-th roll. Then $E(Y_i)=\frac{1+2+\cdots+6}{6}=3.5$.

To find the variance of $Y_i$, use the fact that it is equal to $E(Y_i^2)-(E(Y_i))^2$. And $E((Y_i)^2)=\frac{1^2+2^2+\cdots+6^2}{6}$.

So now we know the mean and the variance of $Y_i$.  Our random variable $X$ is the sum of the $X_i$. So it has mean $100$ times $E(X_i)$, and by independence it has variance $100$ times the variance of $X_i$.

Now we can use the normal approximation, since $X$ is the sum of $100$ independent identically distributed "nice" $Y_i$.

We want $\Pr(330\le X\le 380)$. Maybe we should use the *continuity correction* (if that has been covered in your course). If $W$ is normal mean and variance the same as that of $X$, we have
$$\Pr(330\le X\le 380)\approx \Pr(329.5\le W\le 380.5).$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. Course hasn't cover _continuity correction_ so I'm afraid I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Then find $\Pr(330\le W\le 380)$. The procedure is the one you used, except that you had the wrong mean and variance.

Comment: So $\sigma = \sqrt{(E(X^2) - (EX)^2) * 100 }= 17.08$ But when I aplly this to the formula I get $P(\frac{330 - 100 * 3,5}{17,08} \le Y \le \frac{380 - 100 * 3,5}{17,08}) = P(\frac{-20}{17.08} \le Y \le \frac{30}{17.08}) = P(-1,17 \le Y \le 1,75) =$ And here it gets tricky: $ P(Y \le 1,75) - P(Y \ge-1,17) = \Phi(1,75) - (1 - (P < -1,17)) = \Phi(1,75) - (1 - \Phi(-1,17) = 0,959941 - (1 - (1 - \Phi(1,17)) \approx 0,08$ Where did I made a mistake ?

Comment: Assuming your calculations were correct, we want $\Phi(1.75)-\Phi(-1.17)$. The second is not in tables, but it is equal to $1-\Phi(1.17)$.

Comment: Ok, now I see the mistake. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are welcome.